# I have problem regarding the KUKA_experimental installation

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
I tried to install KUKA manipulators within ROS-Industrial. I followed the following procedure :

1. mkdir -p ~/moveit_ws_2/src  -->   cd /path/to/catkin_ws/src
2. git clone https://github.com/ros-industrial/kuka_experimental.git  -->  cd ..
3. rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src
4. catkin_make

PS I also did source the work space by :   `echo 'source ~/ws_moveit/devel/setup.bash' >> ~/.bashrc`

However by putting this command `roslaunch kuka_experimental kuka_rsi_simulator.launch` I dumped to the following error:

```
[kuka_rsi_simulator.launch] is neither a launch file in package [kuka_experimental] nor is [kuka_experimental] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Could anyone please kindly help me ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301736/i-have-problem-regarding-the-kuka_experimental-installation./) by [MTV1368](https://answers.ros.org/users/34590/mtv1368/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2018-08-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2018-08-27**:
It looks like there are multiple mistakes in the commands you listed. In (1) did you really run `cd /path/to/catkin_ws/src` or did you cd to `~/moveit_ws_2/src`? Are you sourcing the `setup.bash` for `~/ws_moveit` or `~/moveit_ws_2`? What are your ROS environment variables (`env |grep ROS`)?

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2018-08-27**:
Most often the error that you are describing comes from people improperly sourcing the correct `setup.bash` file

**Comment by [MTV1368](https://answers.ros.org/users/34590/mtv1368/) on 2018-08-27**:
Sorry for the typo. I did work in `~/moveit_ws/src`. I followed the exact same way I have been asked on wiki.ros.org  in the same order. I did source it right I am think as roscd works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I also did source the work space by : `echo 'source ~/ws_moveit/devel/setup.bash' >> ~/.bashrc`

That doesn't source the workspace.

Or at least: it will source the workspace only *after* you start a new bash shell, or after you `source $HOME/.bashrc`.

Also: the workspace you created was named `moveit_ws_2`, not `ws_moveit`.

> However by putting this command `roslaunch kuka_experimental kuka_rsi_simulator.launch` I dumped to the following error:

> ```
> [kuka_rsi_simulator.launch] is neither a launch file in package [kuka_experimental] nor is [kuka_experimental] a launch file name
> ```

And this makes sense, as `kuka_experimental` is a metapackage, it doesn't contain any launch files.

If you want to start the `kuka_rsi_simulator.launch` launch file, the command would be:

```
roslaunch kuka_rsi_simulator kuka_rsi_simulator.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1